# What is the best way to print letter and forms with mail merged data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I currently have a customer that needs to print forms, letters, etc.. for their clients.  I wrote an asp.net application that my customer uses to run their business plus a console app that does the printing of these forms and letters.  However, even though the print program works fine, I am not happy with it.  I have these rtf templates that have tags such as <> that I replace with the correct client information by bringing in the template and doing a replace.

I have recently written a program that does a mail merge using Word Interop and it works well but I want to make sure this is the right way to go.  I orignally put it in a windows app but just recently experimented putting it in an asp.net page but when I deployed it to the web server, I got some errors.  I am not really in favor of doing this in an asp.net page but on the flip side, I am not really excited about deploying a windows app to the staff workstations.

If you had a small business customer with about 6 staff members who need to print forms, letters, etc... and merging the letters with their client data, what would you do.  I have an IIS server, SQL server in house and full access to the domain.

I am curious as to what course you would take in this situation.

Comment: Can the resulting letters/forms only be .docx format (i.e. Word 2007/Word 2010) or must you output to the .doc format (i.e. Word 97-Word 2003)?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably get better results and faster if you implement the templates as HTML and then generate them for printing. 
The way I do it is slightly different. We have implemented Crystal Reports and we generate pdf files that could get printed. 
Not sure how you application works or what are the errors but if it runs on windows and not on asp check different classes and any DLL that you would need on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Ms Word successfully in many ASP.NET applications. But the mail merge is done on the client side and not the server and there is nothing to deploy to the server either besides the word "templates" which are simply "files" as far as ASP.NET or IIS are concerned.

If you'r needs are to allow your clients to develop "templates" and be able to use those templates to do mail merge and printing/formating is very important, then using Ms Word is a really good way to go.

It's been a while since I did this however so I don't remember the details off of the top of my head. But the key difference in how you are approaching it and how I did it is that the processing happens on the client machine and yes, your client's users will need Ms Word installed on their machines for this to work.